# NodeJs: Display function's result in html

Tags: html, node.js

How can I get results of my function NODEJS in HTML there is my code:

```
var elasticsearch = require('elasticsearch');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
    host: 'localhost:9200',
    log: 'trace'
});

function getAllMetadata() {
    client.search({
        index: 'info',
        scroll: '30s',
    }, function getAll(error, response) {

        response.hits.hits.forEach(function (body) {
            allresp.push(body.hits);
        })
        console.log('Voilà le nombre de réponse : ' + allresp.length);
        if (response.hits.total !== allresp.length) {
            client.scroll({
                scrollId: response._scroll_id,
                scroll: '30s'
            }, getAllMetadata);
        }
    });
}
getAllMetadata();
```

PS: PLZ how can i display my result "function" in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a `view` and use a templating language like `ejs` to use javascript variables in a view. The view will be a `ejs` file which will be converter to html and rendered.

Here is a good example - https://github.com/chovy/express-template-demo

In that repo there is a `index.ejs` which calls the function `inspect(session)`

Comment: jade is another option to templating. comes default with express4